# Onsubmit does not call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to verify form input via a jQuery get request, but function does not get called.

Tried using just the jQuery (without function), the $.get works and returns proper values. I need the function approach to return false if (and stop form from submitting) if condition is not met.

```
<form onSubmit="return checkName();" action="/register" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="1" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="passconf" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password">
    </div>
    <button id="2" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Register</button>
</form>
<script>
    function checkName() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $.get("/check?username=" + document.getElementById('1').value, function (data, status) {
                    alert(data);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

I expect the function to be called, return true if input verified (and go on with form submission) and false (stop form from submitting) if verification fails.

Comment: might need to be this: `onSubmit="checkName"` also, remove `$(document).ready` that doesn't need to be within a function, same with the `$("button").click`

Comment: You need to return false inside the `checkName` not inside some callback function.

Comment: @jcubic wouldn't `.preventDefault()` be better...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn it would but only if you pass `$event` from inside onsubmit to function `checkName`

Comment: removing `onSubmit` from the html and putting it all in the JavaScript is also much better practice.

Comment: Add a `function checkName() { console.log("checkName"); ...` and you'll see that is *is* calling it, just not returning false, because your return false is inside an ajax callback, so occurs later.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn but the question was about this code, `onSubmit="return checkName();"` I've assume that he want that inside the code.

Comment: @freedomn-m he will need to enable preserve logs (it's in Google chrome dev tools not sure about other browsers) to see logs after request have been sent.

Comment: @jcubic my last comment wasn't directed at you, it was just a general off-topic thought.

Comment: @jcubic good call - could also add `debugger;` statement and step through.  @Maxim Learning to use browser console/debugger will save hours of time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from function not from inside the callback, and you do one if you assign to onsubmit you don't need click handler. And also click handler will not work if you have action on a form.

You need this:

```
function checkName() {
  $.get("/check?username=" + document.getElementById('1').value, function(data, status){
    alert(data);
  });
  return false;
}
```

this is base code, if you want to submit the form if data is false, no user in db then you need something like this (there is probably better way of doing this:

```
var valid = false;
function checkName() {
   if (valid) { // if valid is true it mean that we submited second time
      return;
   }
   $.get("/check?username=" + document.getElementById('1').value, function(data, status){
      if (data) { // we check value (it need to be json/boolean, if it's
                  // string it will be true, even string "false")
         valid = true;
         $('form').submit(); // resubmit the form
      }
   });
   return valid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still form gets submitted.

Comment: By the way, the @.get returns json ({true} or {false})

Comment: @MaximBiryukov string or boolean, try `console.log(typeof data)`

Comment: tried writing console.log(typeof data) below the $.get request, but it doesn't appear in the console.

Comment: [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 53ms - this is the only relevant message i get in the console.

Comment: @MaximBiryukov if you're using Google Chrome you can set preserve logs in console tab (that top one), you can also set preserve logs in network tab. Also If your get request is sending false because user is not in database and the form can be submited then you need to set `if (!data) {`. If console.log say "string" after you set preserve logs then you need to add 3rd argument to `$.get` which should be `'json'`

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `false` from the async handler function. As such, that's not going to stop the form from being sent.

A better solution would be to always prevent the form from being submit then, based on the result of your AJAX request, submit it manually.

Also note that it's much better practice to assign unobtrusive event handlers. As you're using jQuery this is a trivial task. This also gets you access to the Event object which was raised by the form submission in order to cancel it. Try this:

```html
<form action="/register" method="post" id="yourForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="1" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="passconf" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password">
  </div>
  <button id="2" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourForm").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _form = this;
    $.get('/check', { username: $('#1').val() }, function(data, status) {
      // interrogate result here and allow the form submission or show an error as required:
      if (data.isValid) { // just an example property, change as needed
        _form.submit();
      } else {
        alert("Invalid username");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This is way better than my solution, it's always better to use events instead of inline handler in html.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't common practice to put events within the html anymore, as there is `addEventListener`. You can add it directly from the javascript:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', checkName)
```

This allows for easier code to navigate, and makes it easier to read.

We can then prevent the form form doing it's default action by passing the first parameter to the function, and calling `.preventDefault()` as you can see from the modified function below. We no longer need to have `return false` because of it.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', checkName)

function checkName(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $.get("/check?username=" + document.getElementById('1').value, function(data, status) {
    alert(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/register" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="1" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="passconf" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password">
  </div>
  <button id="2" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mark all your fields as required if they cannot be left blank.
For your function you may use the below format which works for me.

```
function checkName() {
  var name = $("#1").val();
  if ('check condition for name which should return true') {} else {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just write the name of the function followed by (). no need to write return on `onsubmit` function call

```js
            function checkName()
            {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("button").click(function(){
                        $.get("/check?username=" + document.getElementById('1').value, function(data, status){
                            alert(data);
                            return false;
        });
      });
    });
            }
```

```html
<form onSubmit="checkName();" action="/register" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="1" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="passconf" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password">
    </div>
    <button id="2" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: 1. yes you do need to return the value to stop the form submission. 2. You're returning `false` from within the async handler function. This still isn't going to work.

Comment: <form onSubmit="checkName()" action="/register" method="post"> - this doesn't call the function either

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, so what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the document.ready and the button event click.

**EDITED**

Adding an event parameter to checkName :

```
<form onSubmit="return checkName(event);" action="/register" method="post" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="1" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="passconf" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password">
    </div>
    <button id="2" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Register</button>
</form>
<script>
     function checkName(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.returnValue = false;
         $.get("/check?username=" + document.getElementById('1').value,
           function(data, status){
           if(data) // here you check if the data is ok 
             document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
           else
            return false;
        });}

</script>
```

Comment: This worked, function gets called, but doesn't stop the form from submitting (

Comment: <script>
                function checkName()
                {
                            $.get("/check?username=" + document.getElementById('1').value, function(data, status){
                                return false;
            });
                }
    </script>            -    even this doesn't stop the form from submitting, though the .get request works

Comment: This will never stop the form from being submit as the `return` is in the callback of the async handler.

Comment: I have fixed my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you replace button type from submit to button and then on button click event, inside get request, if your condition gets true, submit the form explicitly, would help you too achieve what you require.